# Understanding this code method/maths

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve a problem but I just can't seem to get the idea of how it should be solved, like I know to get the coordinates of a square you need the 2 corners to get the other 2 but this just fails, here is the problem:

> Pashmak has fallen in love with an attractive girl called Parmida
>   since one year ago...
>
> Today, Pashmak set up a meeting with his partner in a romantic garden.
>   Unfortunately, Pashmak has forgotten where the garden is. But he
>   remembers that the garden looks like a square with sides parallel to
>   the coordinate axes. He also remembers that there is exactly one tree
>   on each vertex of the square. Now, Pashmak knows the position of only
>   two of the trees. Help him to find the position of two remaining ones.
>
> Input The first line contains four space-separated x1, y1, x2, y2
>   ( - 100 ≤ x1, y1, x2, y2 ≤ 100) integers, where x1 and y1 are
>   coordinates of the first tree and x2 and y2 are coordinates of the
>   second tree. It's guaranteed that the given points are distinct.
>
> Output If there is no solution to the problem, print -1. Otherwise
>   print four space-separated integers x3, y3, x4, y4 that correspond to
>   the coordinates of the two other trees. If there are several solutions
>   you can output any of them.
>
> Note that x3, y3, x4, y4 must be in the range
>   ( - 1000 ≤ x3, y3, x4, y4 ≤ 1000).
>
> Examples
>   input
>    0 0 0 1
>    output
>   1 0 1 1
>   input
>   0 0 1 1
>   output
>   0 1 1 0
>   input
>   0 0 1 2
>   output
>   -1

I also REALLY don't get why the last one can't be solved, although it could be

> 0 2 1 0

as output also here is a code that solved the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    int x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2);

    if (abs(x2-x1) == abs(y2 - y1)){
            y4 = y2;
            y3= y1;
            x4=x1;
            x3=x2;
            printf("%d %d %d %d", x4 ,y4, x3, y3);

    }else if (x1 == x2){

        x4= abs(y2-y1)+x1;
        x3=x4;
        y4=y1;y3=y2;
        printf("%d %d %d %d", x4 ,y4, x3, y3);
    }else if( y2 == y1){
            x3=x1;
            x4=x2;
            y4 = abs(x2-x1) + y2;
            y3 = y4;
            printf("%d %d %d %d", x4 ,y4, x3, y3);
    }else {

        printf("-1");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And if someone can explain the concept behind using such maths or such methods it'd be really appreciated! :)

Comment: It is explicitly stated that the coordinates must be vertices, or corners, of a square. Take a piece of paper with a drawn grid, put a dot on coordinates (0, 0), and (1, 2), then try to draw a square with those coordinates as corners. When you figure out why this is impossible, you will then figure out, all by yourself, why input "0 0 1 2" is invalid. See, it wasn't this hard after all!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes i get it, its a rectangle but... the thing is I wanna know the concept behind such assignments in the code :c if you don't mind explaining them

Comment: The "concept behind such assignments" is to have you learn how to write code. That's it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik lol that's not what I meant, I meant mathematically what's the concept...no need to be rude lmao

Comment: "Mathematically" all sides of a square are equal. There's nothing else to say. This is basic geometry.